# Не получается сделать resize изображения на php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте есть скрипт загрузки изображений на сервер , он срабатывает, но когда хочу загрузить еще копию таких картинок в уменьшенном виде не получается грузятся только обычные изображения выложу весь скрипт и часть как хочу получить уменьенную копию , заранее спасибо за помощь .

```html
$img_width = imageSX($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]);
                $img_height = imageSY($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]);

                $k = round($img_width/IMG_WIDTH,2);

                $img_mini_width = round($img_width/$k);
                $img_mini_height = round($img_height/$k);

                $img_dest_id = imagecreatetruecolor($img_mini_width, $img_mini_height);
                $mini = 'img';
                $result = imagecopyresampled($img_dest_id,
                    $img_id,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    $img_mini_width,
                    $img_mini_height
                );
                $mini = 'img/';
                $img = imagejpeg($img_dest_id, $mini/$name, 100);
```

и весь скрипт

```html
<?php
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/registration/1/my_room/php/session.php');
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bd.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
if(isset($_FILES))
{

//пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
    $error = array();
    $success_list = [];
    $error_list   = [];
    $uploads_dir  =  'images/';
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['error'] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name     = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]);
            $success  = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");


                $img_width = imageSX($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]);
                $img_height = imageSY($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]);

                $k = round($img_width/IMG_WIDTH,2);

                $img_mini_width = round($img_width/$k);
                $img_mini_height = round($img_height/$k);

                $img_dest_id = imagecreatetruecolor($img_mini_width, $img_mini_height);
                $mini = 'img';
                $result = imagecopyresampled($img_dest_id,
                    $img_id,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    $img_mini_width,
                    $img_mini_height
                );
                $mini = 'img/';
                $img = imagejpeg($img_dest_id, $mini/$name, 100);






            if ($success) {
                $success_list[] = $name;
            }
            else {
                $error_list[] = $name;
            }
        }
        else {
            $error_list[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
        }
    }
            $error_list = implode(',', $error_list);
            $success_list = implode(',', $success_list);
            $sqlimage = "INSERT INTO images_big(login, catalog, filename) VALUES(:login, :catalog, :filename)";
            $stmtimg = $pdo->prepare($sqlimage);
            $stmtimg->bindParam(':catalog', $uploads_dir, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtimg->bindParam(':filename', $success_list, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtimg->bindParam(':login', $_GET['login'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmtimg->execute();

      }


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить использовать следующую функцию:

```
function resize($file_input, $file_output, $w_o, $h_o, $percent = false) {
    list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
    if (!$w_i || !$h_i) {
        echo 'Невозможно получить длину и ширину изображения';
        return;
    }
    $types = array('','gif','jpeg','png');
    $ext = $types[$type];
    if ($ext) {
        $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
        $img = $func($file_input);
    } else {
        echo 'Некорректный формат файла';
        return;
    }
    if ($percent) {
        $w_o *= $w_i / 100;
        $h_o *= $h_i / 100;
    }
    if (!$h_o) $h_o = $w_o/($w_i/$h_i);
    if (!$w_o) $w_o = $h_o/($h_i/$w_i);

    $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
    imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i);
    if ($type == 2) {
        return imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);
    } else {
        $func = 'image'.$ext;
        return $func($img_o,$file_output);
    }
}
```

В вашем случае вызов будет примерно таким:

```
resize($_FILES["file"]["name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"], 200, 200);
```

Comment: Извините за назойливость поможете  еще чуть чуть $file_input ек пойму  эту переменую, вроде как понял по ней задается потом размер файла , но у меня всегда пишет 'Невозможно получить длину и ширину изображения'

Comment: Вы передаете $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key] в качестве первого и второго параметра?

Comment: Нужно передать исходное изображение в качестве первого параметра и файл результат в качестве второго

Comment: Я делаю так http://pastebin.ru/46FWU0kd спасибо за проявленную помощь извините, если что не понимаю

Comment: Попробуйте в таком виде http://pastebin.ru/nyLGWLOM использовать, сохраняться должно в ту же папку только перед названием будет "small_".

Comment: да, все заработало я Вам заявку в вк отправил, если объясните, где я так затупил